# Float block element without specifying width

Tags: html, css

I am reading the book **Head First HTML and CSS** and there it is written that a requirement for any floating element is that it must have a width. I tried floating right a div element without specifying width on it, and the float property works(it moves the div furthest right as possible) as supposed. Does this mean that there is an error in the book, or it is something that i am missing ?

Comment: Probably...but without knowing the full context we can't really comment. A vague reference to "something in a book" doesn't help much.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have floated elements with no `width` values declared in the cascade. Then, through a [defaulting](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#defaulting) process, the specified value will be the [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value).

For [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property), the initial value is `auto`.

CSS explains what should happen when a [floated non-replaced element](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#float-width) has `width: auto`:

> If [`width`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-width) is computed as `auto`, the used value is the
>   "shrink-to-fit" width.
>
> Calculation of the shrink-to-fit width is similar to calculating the
>   width of a table cell using the automatic table layout algorithm.
>   Roughly: calculate the preferred width by formatting the content
>   without breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur,
>   and also calculate the preferred *minimum* width, e.g., by trying all
>   possible line breaks. CSS 2.1 does not define the exact algorithm.
>   Thirdly, find the *available width*: in this case, this is the width of
>   the containing block minus the used values of `margin-left`,
>   `border-left-width`, `padding-left`, `padding-right`,
>   `border-right-width`, `margin-right`, and the widths of any relevant
>   scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is:
>
> ```
> min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)
> ```

The "shrink-to-fit" algorithm is now called [fit-content measure](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fit-content-measure).

Answer (score -3):

`float:right` is simple stacking of elements, left to right until a line width is filled, then top to bottom. Like writing an English newspaper page.

`float:left` is used for things like a sidebar, it would take up the whole page, **unless** its width is constrained.  This is why the `width` must be specified.

Comment: "*it would take up the whole page*" seems to mean [fill-available measure](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fill-available-measure). But the [fit-content measure](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-sizing/#fit-content-measure) is used instead.